# Не показывает изображение в окне

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, разработка-игр, pygame

Кораблик должен находится с левого края. Мне кажется я его сделал, но он за пределами окна летит, так как коллизия срабатывает.

[image: problem image]

**main.py**:

```
import pygame
import random as rnd
from random import randint, randrange

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Final Project')
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 400
SIZE = 128
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
bg_img = pygame.image.load('228.jpg')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


ship_img = pygame.image.load('ship228.png')

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, keysList):
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 15
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, SIZE, SIZE)
        self.keyUP = keysList[0]
        self.keyDOWN = keysList[1]
    def draw_ship(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect)
        screen.blit(self.rect, ship_img)


Ship228 = Ship('white', 15 ,HEIGHT / 2 - SIZE, (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN))

block_x = WIDTH - 50
block_y = HEIGHT // 2
block_speed = 10
asteroidslist = list()

run = True
for i in range(5):
    asteroids = pygame.Rect(randint(1000, 2000), randint(0, HEIGHT - 50), 25, 25)
    asteroidslist.append(asteroids)

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # if key[pygame.K_w] and y > 0:
    #     y -= self.speed
    # if key[pygame.K_s] and y < HEIGHT - s_h:
    #     y += self.speed

    for x in (asteroidslist):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'red', x)
        x.x -= 10
        if x.x < 0 - 25:
            x.x, x.y = (rnd.randint(1000, 2000)), (rnd.randint(0, HEIGHT - 50))
        # if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(ship, asteroids):
            if pygame.Rect.colliderect(Ship228.rect, asteroids):
                run = False

    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

[image: background image]

[image: SHIP IMAGE!!!]

Comment: кораблик должен находится с самого лева, мне кажется я его сделал но он за пределами окна летит так как колизия срабатывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import random
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 1000
height = 600

size = (width, height)

window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")                              # !!! установите свое .jpg
background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (width, height)) 

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Helvetica",50)
score = 0

# pygame.mixer.music.load("bibi.mp3")


class Piece(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x=width/2, y=height/2):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load('ball.png')                              # !!! установите свое .png
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 0
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self, *args):
        up, down, right, left = args

        if self.rect.y < 0:
            self.rect.y = 0
        if self.rect.y + self.rect.size[1] > height:
            self.rect.y = height - self.rect.size[1]

        if up:
            self.rect.y -= 10
        if down:
            self.rect.y += 10


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 20))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.y = random.randrange(height - self.rect.height)
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width+40, width+100)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(5, 13)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(-2, 2)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.rect.x -= self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(height - self.rect.height)
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(width + 40, width + 100)
            self.speedx = random.randrange(10, 13)
            self.speedy = random.randrange(-3, 3)
            global score
            score += 1


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
mermiler = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(10):
    bullet = Bullet()
    all_sprites.add(bullet)
    mermiler.add(bullet)

piece = Piece()
all_sprites.add(piece)

while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:sys.exit()

    up, down, right, left = keys[pygame.K_UP], keys[pygame.K_DOWN], keys[pygame.K_RIGHT], keys[pygame.K_LEFT]
    all_sprites.update(up, down, right, left)
   
    window.blit(background,(0,0))                                            # !!!   
    all_sprites.draw(window)                                                 # !!!

    situation = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(piece, mermiler, False)

    if situation:
#         pygame.mixer.music.play()
    
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.wait(1000)
        sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**background.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ball.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: здравствуйте что значат *args в вашем коде? и что они делают

Comment: @Øfdream добавьте `print(f'{args}')`, запустите приложение и нажимайте клавиши стрелок и смотрите что будет выдавать принт.